# How to integrate Rails with PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ruby-on-rails-4, phonegap-build

I've been looking at PhoneGap recently and I would like to use it for one of my projects, but I'm a little confused as to how it works. It says you can use HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But what can I use for the backend? What I want to make is pretty basic, I want users and for them to have basic profiles, but I use Rails for that. Can I use Rails with PhoneGap or will I have to learn a new JavaScript framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap is client side only. It gives you a Javascript API to access hardware features and other phone specific stuff. It has no connection with, or opinions about what you use for your server backend. It doesn't even need a server backend at all.

It is your Javascript code that you write for your client that communicate with your backend, so you can have it any way you want. Sure, Rails will be just fine.

Comment: Interesting, I'm still a little confused though. For example, if I created an entire Rails application, I would just "upload" all of my HTML, CSS and JavaScript to Phonegap, but where would I store my backend so that they could communicate? Also, I couldn't use embedded Ruby in my views then either? Sorry if this is all basic stuff I'm pretty new to programming in general.

Comment: Your backend goes on some server wherever you want it. The client side javascript you write (which is using phonegap to access phone features) communicates with your backend using the same protocols as it would if it was running without phonegap just as a web page.